# Как получить данные из строки?

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть строка:

```
Здесь аудио и фото[ATTACHMENT]jpg/c2cbd77405f5802457bff4ff07c23cc76a6ca4f9291ef99b23bd0570dc23de30/1572189798_7c3bb82d9ace96a798ca.jpg[/ATTACHMENT][ATTACHMENT]mp3/f97aa34259401559d4592f42f5a0b04a162f1c46b05f4c17e5cb79ee0a3ccd94/abba_-_happy-new-year.mp3[/ATTACHMENT]
```

Как мне получить содержимое строки между [ATTACHMENT][/ATTACHMENT] и преобразовать в массив методами js и методами PHP?

Comment: Попробуйте регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Средствами PHP к примеру можно так:

```
$str = 'Здесь аудио и фото[ATTACHMENT]jpg/c2cbd77405f5802457bff4ff07c23cc76a6ca4f9291ef99b23bd0570dc23de30/1572189798_7c3bb82d9ace96a798ca.jpg[/ATTACHMENT][ATTACHMENT]mp3/f97aa34259401559d4592f42f5a0b04a162f1c46b05f4c17e5cb79ee0a3ccd94/abba_-_happy-new-year.mp3[/ATTACHMENT]';

$arr = [];
! preg_match_all('~\[ATTACHMENT]\K[^[]+(?=\[/ATTACHMENT])~', $str, $arr) ?: $arr = $arr[0];

var_export($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
array (
  0 => 'jpg/c2cbd77405f5802457bff4ff07c23cc76a6ca4f9291ef99b23bd0570dc23de30/1572189798_7c3bb82d9ace96a798ca.jpg',
  1 => 'mp3/f97aa34259401559d4592f42f5a0b04a162f1c46b05f4c17e5cb79ee0a3ccd94/abba_-_happy-new-year.mp3',
)
```

**UPD**: Средствами JS можно так:

```js
let str = 'Здесь аудио и фото[ATTACHMENT]jpg/c2cbd77405f5802457bff4ff07c23cc76a6ca4f9291ef99b23bd0570dc23de30/1572189798_7c3bb82d9ace96a798ca.jpg[/ATTACHMENT][ATTACHMENT]mp3/f97aa34259401559d4592f42f5a0b04a162f1c46b05f4c17e5cb79ee0a3ccd94/abba_-_happy-new-year.mp3[/ATTACHMENT]';
let re = /(?<=\[ATTACHMENT])[^[]+(?=\[\/ATTACHMENT])/g;
let myArray = str.match(re);

console.log( myArray );
```